# Launch PreferenceDialog from Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences

In my main activity, I'm checking to see if a student has stored their id in shared preferences
In `onResume`, I check if the string is empty, and if it is, I launch a dialog

```
 private void showNoStudentIdDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_no_id, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setView(view).setTitle(getString(R.string.no_id_dialog_title));
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            openSettingsDetail();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

**openSettingDetail**

```
public boolean openSettingsDetail() {
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
    return true;
}
```

The intent correctly launches my `SettingsActivty` and loads the correct preferences. However, I still have to manually touch the ID preference to launch the dialog for it. Can I achieve this touch / click programatically from the MainActivity when I launch the intent?

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupActionBar();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.student_id_key)));
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_timetable_key)));

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);
    }
}


/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this);
}

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */
private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}


/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference.getKey().equals(preference.getContext().getString(R.string.student_id_key))) {
            setPreferenceSummary(preference, stringValue);
        } else if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

private static void setPreferenceSummary(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue = value.toString();
    String key = preference.getKey();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
        // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    } else if (key.equals(preference.getContext().getString(R.string.student_id_key))) {
        @TimetableSyncAdapter.ServerStatus int status = Utility.getServerStatus(preference.getContext());
        switch (status) {
            case TimetableSyncAdapter.SERVER_STATUS_OK:
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                break;
            case TimetableSyncAdapter.SERVER_STATUS_UNKNOWN:
                preference.setSummary(preference.getContext().getString(R.string.pref_student_id_unknown_description, value.toString()));
                break;
            case TimetableSyncAdapter.SERVER_STATUS_ID_INVALID:
                preference.setSummary(preference.getContext().getString(R.string.pref_student_id_invalid_id, value.toString()));
                break;
            default:
                // Note --- if the server is down we still assume the value
                // is valid
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
    } else {
        // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }

}

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.student_id_key)));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_timetable_key)));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            getActivity().finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}


/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            getActivity().finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            getActivity().finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

**pref_general.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mcgowan.timetable.itsligotimetables">


<com.mcgowan.timetable.itsligotimetables.StudentIdEditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@string/student_id_default"
    android:hint="@string/student_id_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:key="@string/student_id_key"
    android:maxLength="9"
    custom:minLength="9"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name" />


<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_timetable_type_classes"
    android:entries="@array/timetable_type_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/timetable_type_list_values"
    android:key="@string/pref_timetable_key"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_timetable_type" />
```

This dialog is displayed first, which then launches an intent

[image]

The intent launches the following screen:

[image]

and I have to click on the Student ID preference to launch the following

[image]

I want to skip the step in the second image, and programatically launch the last one with the intent

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupActionBar();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.student_id_key)));
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_timetable_key)));

  if (<student ID is empty)) {
    showNoStudentIdDialog();
  }

}
```

Yes, I know, but I'm really confused what you are asking. If you want to show the dialog, just call the method to show it wherever and under whatever condition you want ...

Comment: If you want to show the dialog, just show it. Like I put in the code in my answer. I am not understanding what's preventing you from doing that.

Comment: This is a check thats made when the app is first launched, before the user loads the settings activity. I've added another image in my question

Comment: How can I launch the specific preference from MainActivity?

Comment: You can't access the preferences defined in a preference activity from some other activity. I think your best bet is to roll your own custom preference, then share the dialog code between the activities. E.g., the preference is just a `Preference`, and you set a click listener to show a dialog ... and use that same dialog in `MainActivity`.